# QwtPlot sending runtime exception when trying to show a curve with 8000 points

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I'm trying to show two curves in a `QwtPlot` and `replot` each 20 miliseconds. But when I run my program it throws a runtime exception.

Here are my variables:

```
QwtPlot * spectrum = new QwtPlot();
QwtPlotCurve * Tcurve = new QwtPlotCurve();
QwtPlotCurve * Scurve = new QwtPlotCurve();
QpolygonF Tpoints;
QpolygonF Spoints;
const int count = 1;
```

And here is the code for every time I replot spectrum :

```
for(i=0;i<4006;i+=count)
{
 Tpoints << QPointF(i,intArray[i]);
}
for(;i<8012;i+=count)
{
 Spoints << QPointF(i-4005,intArray[i]);
}

Tcurve->setSamples(Tpoints);
Scurve->setSamples(Spoints);

Tcurve->attach(spectrum);
Scurve->attach(spectrum);

spectrum->replot();
```

The `intArray` array is updated every millisecond through a UDP socket connection but the spectrum is updated each 20 milliseconds.

Farther info: The size of the QwtPlot is 1000x280
Here is the exception window:

[image: Exception Window]

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: "Visual Studio Just-In-time Debugger" window pops up and this is the messege : "An unhandled win32 exception occured in myProg.exe.[3056]

Comment: When I change the `count` const to 50 or 100 it works ok, but with `count` as 1 it doesn't work...

Comment: What size has `intArray`? Why you need to change 'count' / Why you don't simply write `i++`?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: It's an array of `short int` type and size of `8013` bytes.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @guneykayim: I've added the exception window to the question, no line numbers I'm afrid :(

Comment: You should first figure out which line is throwing the exception. Just debug your code and find which code block throws the exception. It will be easier to find the problem if you first localize it.

Comment: Or place some qDebug's in your code if you are too lazy to debug...

Comment: @guneykayim: Since this is a runtime exception outside the QtCreator I don't think I can figure it out using the debugger in Qt, am I right?

Comment: No you are not right, you can run a program in debug mode and still get a runtime exception. QtCreator just helps you to debug the program. There is no such thing that if you run the program from QtCreator and it doesn't give runtime exception.

Comment: You are going out of index! Your iteration over array is wrong. I'm repeating once again: Why you need to increment `i` variable on `count` instead of `1`???

Comment: @DmitrySazonov: Since `intArray` is an array of 8013 size and I am counting to 8011 I don't think that I'm going out of index. My point in using count is to control the amount of point that can be shown in the plot, for example, if I change count to 20 only about 400 points will be shown in the plot, this way I tested if the plot could work with less points in it and when I tested it there was no runtime exception.